# Value defaultContentView not found

Tags: ios, xcode, github

I downloaded this project : https://github.com/YannickSteph/EasyPopup 
In it the value defaultContentView is declared. I cannot find where it is declared please help!!

Answer (score 0):

It's declared in `ViewController` lines 250-272. `defaultContentView` is a function.

```
/**
    Create content view

    :param: width     CGFloat
    :param: height    CGFloat
    :param: imageName String

    :returns: UIView
    */
    func defaultContentView(width:CGFloat,height:CGFloat, imageName:String, offSet:CGFloat = -200) -> UIView {
        var contentView = UIView(frame: CGRectMake(0, 0, width, height ))


        // create the title label
        let titleLabel = UILabel(frame: CGRectMake(0, 0, width, 30))
        titleLabel.text = "Example blabla, Cool popup !"
        titleLabel.textAlignment = .Center
        titleLabel.font = UIFont.systemFontOfSize(17)
        contentView.addSubview(titleLabel)

        contentView.setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints(false)


        titleLabel.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizing.FlexibleLeftMargin |
            UIViewAutoresizing.FlexibleRightMargin |
            UIViewAutoresizing.FlexibleTopMargin |
            UIViewAutoresizing.FlexibleBottomMargin
        titleLabel.center = CGPointMake(view.bounds.midX, view.bounds.midY + offSet)
        self.defaultImage(contentView,name: imageName)

        return contentView
    }
```

Comment: Yes I know but defaultContentView but it is called before it is declared anywhere else? could it be created not in the ViewController??

Comment: I don't think you understand... `defaultContentView` is a _function_ that returns a `UIView`. It's not a variable that's declared anywhere. Here in this line for instance, `let contentView = self.defaultContentView...` your assigning `contentView` to be the return value of `defaultContentView()`.